# UITableViewCell press to show a view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, menu, hyperlink

I have followed [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/Q6YTdRu8H_c) which will create a menu that you can slide over or tap on a button to slide out from the side (like facebook's iOS app). In the menu there are cells from a table view that I want to link to another view that will close the menu and open that view. If you know any other projects or tutorials that could do what I am asking for, please let me know. I have tried [ecslidingviewcontroller](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) but it will not work with what I am trying to do with my app (have an rss reader in a page that you can access from the menu) so, that is why I am looking for something that will either be a different sliding menu that can have different views be linked from the menu's table view or recommendations to the current code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one https://github.com/izqui/SHSidebarController pretty good. You basically create separate controller for each link or menu item on the side